# Auto fill React Native TextInput shows the end text

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to auto fill a TextInput with some larger text that needs more space to render completely than available space. Everything works fine but text is visible from the end. What should I do so that text is visible from the start?

[image]

Comment: @zvona I am seeking for a solution where I can show the text from start, no matter whether the ending text is visible or not. I am trying to find a possibility of showing the text from starting instead of ending without changing dimensions of the TextInput; doesn't matter if the text is not comletely visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution and posting so that someone searching can find it and save time.

I used the selection property of TextInput http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selection

I used onBlur and onFocus event to set selection(position cursor)

Here's the code sample(not full code):

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        selection: {
            start: 0,
            end: 0
        }
    }
    render() {
         return <TextInput
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    style={{
                        width: 100,
                        height: 40
                    }}
                    onBlur={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selection: {
                                start: 0,
                                end: 0
                            }
                        })
                    }}
                    onFocus={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selection: {
                                start: this.state.text.length,
                                end: this.state.text.length
                            }
                        }, () => {
                            this.setState({ selection: null })
                        })
                    }}
                    selection={this.state.selection}
                />
    }
```

Explanation:
When the components mounts the initial position remains (0, 0) and when user starts typing that is onFocus I first set the position at the end that is the length of the text(so that user need not manually jump from start to end) and then reset to null else the cursor will always remain at the position where we had set it(text.length before user started typing).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you style the TextInput. 
Wrap the TextInput in a View and give it flex 1 and also the View flex 1.
Then make sure that other components in the same row don’t have flex 1. That will give any remaining space to the TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

I made you an example of expanding the dimensions (width) based on `onContentSizeChange`: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/expanding-textinput

If you have any questions about the code, please feel free to comment.